# Trying to run a report on SharePoint Online through PowerShell, I receive Error 403

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I am trying to extract a report from SharePoint through PowerShell and brings an Error 403

> "Get-PnpList : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
> At line:21 char:12
>
> - $library = Get-PnPList -Identity $libraryName -Includes RoleAssignmen ..."

Has anyone encountered this problem before or know how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your permission level on the list?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have appropriate permission for the site collection where the library is located, such as Full control permission.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
Yes, I have noticed that.  Where can I set that?

Comment: Please contact the senior administrator to add you as a site owner in that site collection .